# React-Native Dynamic properties in state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a dynamic list of objects and need to generate switch components for them.

```
var dynamicObject = [{ name: 'first item', value: false }, { name: 'second item', value: true}, ..];
this.setState({ dynamicObject });
```

For update

```
onSwitchChange = (name, newValue) => {
   var obj = {...this.state.dynamicObject};
   obj.find(x => x.name === name).value = newValue;
   this.setState({ dynamicObject: obj });
}
```

But, if I click fast enough on multiple switches, on the first one would change and others will revert back to the old state. This is because of the async nature of `setState`. How can I solve this issue?

EDIT1

I tried this one too. Still not working

```
this.setState(currentState => {
  var obj = currentState.dynamicObject;
  obj.find(x => x.name === name).value = newValue;
  return { dynamicObject: obj };
});
```

EDIT2

I am creating the elements using a function in `render()` like this,

```
const SwitchItem = ({ label, value, onSwitchChange }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <View>
                <Text>{label}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Switch value={value} onValueChange={onSwitchChange} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

If I use it as a component in the loop

`<SwitchItem key={i} label={item.name} value={item.value} onSwitchChange={val => onSwitchChange(item.name, val) } />` it fails.

But the method in EDIT1 works if I do this

`{SwitchItem({label: item.name, value: item.value, onSwitchChange: val => onSwitchChange(item.name, val) })}`

What is the difference between the two methods?

Now if I click on multiple switches fast, they are changing, but If I double click on a switch that is OFF, it will stay at ON position only and is neglecting the successive clicks for a time?.

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` doesn't update state immediately. Instead it will queue the change and update state in batches. When you rapidly invoke `onSwitchChange`, the line `var obj = {...this.state.dynamicObject}` may be using stale data if the batch hasn't been processes.

The fix is to use `this.setState` with a function argument rather than an object. When React processes the batch it will invoke the function with the up to date state object.

```
onSwitchChange = (name, newValue) => {
   this.setState(({ dynamicObject }) => {
      var obj = {...this.state.dynamicObject};
      obj.find(x => x.name === name).value = newValue;
      return { dynamicObject: obj } 
   });
}
```

For more info checkout [React.setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: The OP did try the callback pattern as mentioned in his question

Comment: gah, I missed it

Comment: Updated the question